# Refactoring: Simple regex

Tags: php, regex

lLets say I have the following: `$string = 'New+York-NY` and where `+` is I want a `\s` and where `-` is I want `', '`. The formatted string would appear as `New York, NY`.

Here is my code:
        $string = 'New+York-NY';

```
    $formattedLocation = preg_replace('/[+]/', ' ', $location);
    $formattedLocation = preg_replace('/-/', ', ', $formattedLocation);

    echo $formattedLocation;
```

This code works. However it is ugly and I would like to refactor it (if possible). I tried:

```
    $formattedLocation = preg_replace('/[+]/', ' ', $location) && preg_replace('/-/', ', ', $location);
```

This however doesn't work and is also still ugly. Should I be using a different function? Or should my regex be different? Please don't suggest wrapping it in a custom function (that's not the answer I'm looking for).

Thanks

Comment: Why do you consider your initial code ugly? It's readable and doesn't get more effective as long as you're using regexp.

Comment: for these kind of literal replacement you don't need to use preg_replace, use only str_replace that is faster.

Comment: I think it's ugly because it is repetitive. I would Like to shorten it without sacrificing simplicity. (if possible)

Comment: Wrap the replacement inside a function - that'S the usual way to ensure DRY. Or just don't use preg_repalce at all, see @p.s.w.g's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something this simple do you really need to use regular expressions? Try using [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$formattedLocation = str_replace(array('+', '-'), array(' ', ', '), $location);
```